# Restricting App use within particular geo graphicalarea

Tags: android, geolocation

How can i restrict use of my app within 1KM of geo coordinate if user enter in that area then sending notification to that user

Answer (score 0):

google has provided apis that can leverage their framework to do geofencing.

Here is the developer page for it http://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html

Also, a git sample for a project https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location

You can then set up a geofence for the requisite location with a size of 1Km and choose either entry or dwell transitions for the geofence to notify the User.

Hope it helps!